# How to host multiple Node apps on same website?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, deployment, backend

I'm a beginner Web Developer and I'm currently building my portfolio website with Node JS. I finished the frontend and it has a few sections, one of them being Projects, where I've displayed some of the Frontend and Full Stack projects that I've built using Node JS and Express for the Backend. The Full stack projects are stand-alone apps, with their own package.json and node_modules folder, that can be run independently but are not deployed on a server yet, only on localhost on port 3000.

When I deploy my website, I would like to host these projects on my website and create routes for them, such as "www.mywebsite.com/project1", which would render "project1". I'm not too sure how to go about doing that so I would appreciate any suggestions or advice that would point me to the right direction.

I tried creating a "projects" folder in my portfolio application where I've included all my Front-End and Full Stack projects as folders and attempted to create a route for one of my Frontend projects like this:

```
app.get("/project1", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/projects/project1/index.html");
})
```

This works for the Front-End projects but I'm not sure how to route my Full Stack projects because for most of them, the app.get("/", etc.) contains more stuff than just rendering the Frontend.

Thanks for your time and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use subdomain for multipel instance

Comment: You can use a proxy like nginx to redirect different paths to different ports on your server so http://somedomain.com/project1 goes to one of your servers on port X and http://somedomain.com/project2 goes to a different one of your servers on port Y - all transparent to the client.